# Finding Integral over a Region Bounded by 4 curves

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Hi there I tried solving the problem at the bottom, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. I attempted to draw it first and then came up with the following bounds of integration.

$$\int_{2x}^{x/4}\int_{1/x}^{4/x} e^{-xy/2} dydx$$

However, I couldn't compute this to a numerical value. Normally, I would use strictly numbers rather than variables for the bounds of the outermost integral, but if you sketch the curve, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't get the correct region if the outermost integral had numerical bounds. Is there any way to calculate this problem that I'm not seeing?

Let R be the region bounded by $y = 2x$, $y = \frac{x}{4}$, $y = \frac{4}{x}$, $y = \frac{1}{x}$.

Evaluate
$\iint_R e^{-xy/2} dA$

Edit:
I overlooked the fact that there are 2 regions bounded by these curves of equal area. I am only looking to integrate the bounded region in the first quadrant.

Comment: Looking at the region, I would guess that you have to split it up into multiple regions, unless you switch to polar coordinates (which still doesn't look very nice). You are correct that you must have constant bounds on the outer integral.

Comment: The limits on the outer integral are incorrect. Also, the first three equations already bound a region, so the addition of a fourth curve which crosses that already bounded region only confuses the question of what region is intended. This is an improperly posed question.

Comment: @kccu Is there an easy way to break it up and solve it? Or is this honestly just going to be a tedious problem?

Comment: There are two identical closed regions bounded by these curves. Are you supposed to find the area of one or both?

Comment: Are you evaluating the integral of $e^{-xy/2}$ or the area? I know you said 'looking for the area', but the you also said 'Evaluate ∬Re−xy/2dA∬Re−xy/2dA '.

Comment: @ploosu2 Sorry. I used the wrong terminology. I fixed it. I'm not looking for the area. I'm evaluating the integral.

Comment: Try “straightening out” the sides by using the transformation $u=y/x$, $v=xy$. If all goes well, the integrand will be something tractable, and you’ll be integrating over an axis-aligned rectangle.

Comment: I’ve edited the title of the question to better reflect what you’re actually asking, since already two answers show how to compute the region’s area instead of the integral that you’re asking about.

Answer (score 4):

To evaluate this integral most efficiently, it's better to switch to new variables that better reflect the region of integration (and won't ruin the integrand). Here's an outline of the solution.

Let $u=\frac{y}{x}$. Then two of the bounding equations, $y=\frac{x}{4}$ and $y=2x$ tell us that $u$ ranges in the interval $u\in\left[\frac{1}{4},2\right]$.

Let $v=xy$. Then the other two of the bounding equations, $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and $y=\frac{4}{x}$ tell us that $v$ ranges in the interval $v\in[1,4]$.

Now the given double integral can be rewritten as
$$\iint_R e^{xy/2}\,dA=\int_{1/4}^2\int_1^4 e^{-v/2}\,|J|\,dv\,du,$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian of this change of variables.

Solving $u=\frac{y}{x}$ and $v=xy$ for $x$ and $y$, we find that $x=u^{-1/2}v^{1/2}$ and $y=u^{1/2}v^{1/2}$. Therefore the Jacobian is
$$J=\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} -\frac{1}{2}u^{-3/2}v^{1/2} & \frac{1}{2}u^{-1/2}v^{-1/2} \\ \frac{1}{2}u^{-1/2}v^{1/2} & \frac{1}{2}u^{1/2}v^{-1/2} \end{vmatrix}=-\frac{1}{2}u^{-1}.$$

Then the integral can be computed further as
$$\int_{1/4}^2\int_1^4 e^{-v/2}\,|J|\,dv\,du=\int_{1/4}^2\int_1^4 e^{-v/2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}u^{-1}\,dv\,du=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_{1/4}^2 u^{-1}\,du\cdot\int_1^4 e^{-v/2}\,dv \\ =\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left[\ln|u|\right]_{1/4}^2\cdot\left[-2e^{-v/2}\right]_1^4=-\left(\ln2-\ln\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdot\left(e^{-2}-e^{-1/2}\right)=\left(e^{-1/2}-e^{-2}\right)\ln8.$$

Comment: This is a bit more than an “outline.” Looks like a pretty complete solution to me.

Comment: @amd: :-) I wanted to skip some steps, but then got carried away when typing it...

Comment: BTW, you can avoid having to solve for $x$ and $y$ and dealing with all of the fractional exponents: $\left|{\partial(u,v)\over\partial(x,y)}\right|=-2y/x=-2u$, so $J=-{1\over2u}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph showing one of the two identical regions bounded by these graphs:

[image]

Where the red curve is $y=2x$, the blue is $y=\frac{x}{4}$, green is $y=\frac{4}{x}$, and yellow is $y=\frac{1}{x}$. To calculate the area, we can find the sum of the areas $A_1, A_2,$ and $A_3$, where $A_1$ is the area between the red and yellow curves from the intersection of the yellow and red curves to the intersection of the red and green curves, $A_2$ is the area between the green and yellow curves from the intersection between the red and green curves to the intersection between the yellow and blue curves, and $A_3$ is the area between the green and blue curves from  the intersection between the blue and yellow curves to the intersection between the green and blue curves. Let us calculate these one at a time.

First we calculate $A_1$. To do this, we need the x-coordinates of the intersection points of the yellow and red curves and the red and green curves. These x-coordinates are $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and $\sqrt 2$ (you can verify this for yourself). Then
$$A_1=\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}^{\sqrt 2} (2x-\frac{1}{x})dx$$
When we evaluate the indefinite integral, we get
$$\int (2x-\frac{1}{x})dx=x^2-\ln x+C$$
So
$$A_1=(2-\ln (\sqrt 2))-(\frac{1}{2}-\ln (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}))$$
$$A_1=2-\frac{1}{2}\ln (2)-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln (2)$$
$$A_1=\frac{3}{2}-\ln 2$$
Now we want to find $A_2$. The bounds for this area are $\sqrt 2$ and $2$, so
$$A_2=\int_{\sqrt 2}^{2} (\frac{4}{x}-\frac{1}{x})dx$$
$$A_2=\int_{\sqrt 2}^{2} (\frac{3}{x})dx$$
This is a standard integral, and we can immediately say that
$$A_2=3\ln(2)-3\ln(\sqrt 2)$$
$$A_2=\frac{3}{2}\ln2$$
Now we have one more area to find. The bounds for $A_3$ are $2$ and $4$, so
$$A_3=\int_{2}^{4} (\frac{4}{x}-\frac{x}{4})dx$$
And the indefinite integral is equal to
$$\int (\frac{4}{x}-\frac{x}{4})dx=4\ln x -\frac{x^2}{8}+C$$
So
$$A_3=(4\ln 4 -\frac{4^2}{8})-(4\ln 2 -\frac{2^2}{8})$$
$$A_3=8\ln 2 -\frac{16}{8}-4\ln 2 +\frac{4}{8}$$
$$A_3=4\ln 2 -\frac{3}{2}$$
Now we have all three areas, and we need only find their sum. The entire area $A$ is
$$A=A_1+A_2+A_3$$
$$A=\frac{3}{2}-\ln 2+\frac{3}{2}\ln2+4\ln 2 -\frac{3}{2}$$
$$A=\frac{3}{2}\ln2+3\ln 2$$
$$A=\frac{9}{2}\ln2$$
Which should be the final answer. Is this correct?

Comment: The question’s title notwithstanding, the OP doesn’t want the area of the region, he wants to integrate a function over the region.

Comment: I understand that. I provided a function (or rather, three of them) that, when integrated over, sum to the area of the region.

Comment: That you did, but you haven’t answered the question that the OP actually asked (title of the post notwithstanding), which is about the integral of a certain function over the region, not the region’s area per se.