# Finding the area bounded by 4 parabolas

Tags: integration, conic-sections

**The question is**:
 Find the area (R) bounded by the following parabolas:

(1). $y=x^2$

(2). $4y=x^2$

(3). $y^2=2x$

(4). $y^2=3x$

I am looking for a solution with double integrals.

I tried to do it with jacobian found out u={1,4} and v={2,3} but unlike this ([Finding Integral over a Region Bounded by 4 curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276894/finding-integral-over-a-region-bounded-by-4-curves)) one i cannot evaluate. Because it is asking the area.

Edit: Alternative Solution

After determining u and v values draw a u-v graph and find the area. (You will get a small rectangle.) Let's call it A.
Then determine the jacobian (j) and since j is "R/A" you will get the answer.

Comment: Along with the question please also post the context of the problem, the work you did on it and where you got stuck.

Comment: just sketch their plot, determine intersection points, thus range of $x$ and $y$, and split the range of $x$ (or $y$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: It is by no means clear what the bounded area should be: if that means the area inside all parabolas, then first and third parabola are enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the area of a region is equivalent to integrate the constant function $1$
over that region. I will assume you are trying to find the area of following region:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
&1 \le \frac{x^2}{y} \le 4  & \text{(below (1), above (2))}\\
\text{and}& 2 \le \frac{y^2}{x} \le 3 & \text{(left of (3), right of (4))}
\end{array}$$

Change variable to $u = \frac{x^2}{y}, v = \frac{y^2}{x}$, the region becomes
$$ 1 \le u \le 4\quad\text{ and }\quad 2 \le v \le 3$$
Since $x = u^{\frac23}v^{\frac13}$ and $y = u^{\frac13}v^{\frac23}$,
the Jacobian $J$ equals to
$$J = \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right| = \left|\begin{matrix}
\frac{2x}{3u} & \frac{x}{3v}\\
\frac{y}{3u} & \frac{2y}{3v}
\end{matrix}\right| = \frac{2^2-1}{3^2}\frac{xy}{uv} = \frac13 $$
As a result, the area of the region is
$$R = \int_2^3 \int_1^4 J dudv = \frac13\int_2^3 \int_1^4 dudv = \frac13(3-2)(4-3) = 1$$